# Created new Branch from develop and how to push

Tags: git, github

I have created a new branch while working in develop branch as feature/parsing. My question if how it will have all the new coming changes of the develop branch? or how will I be merging them in this current working branch.

Comment: It's all up to you, really. When the feature in question is complete, you could either [*merge*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) the branch into `develop` or [*rebase*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) it to `develop`. I feel that your question is too vague to stay open, though.

Answer (score 1):

consider current Branch is development
and a new branch from development is feature

1) to merge changes from feature to development

checkout development branch

`git checkout -b development`

merge feature branch to it

`git merge -b feature`

2) to merge changes from development to feature

checkout feature and merge development to it

Answer (score 1):

I have to reread your question a couple of times.
But I am going to assume the following of what you are trying to say (do comment if it isn't)

1. You are currently working on development branch (lets call it branch with "development" as its name)
2. You created a new branch from "development" branch (lets call it branch with "newBranch" as its name)

And you want to know

1. How do you get all new changes that happens on "development" branch on remote to your current working branch (which is "newBranch" branch).

If that is so, then the following is how to do it

---

Always ensure you are in the correct branch by

```
git branch
```

To know all the branch you have (on remote & local)

```
git branch -a
```

The most IMPORTANT thing here is, you have to be in the branch you want to pull and merge the changes from remote.

If you are in "newBranch" and do (assuming your remote "development" branch name is "development" as well):

```
git pull (or git pull --rebase) origin development
```

It will merge into your "newBranch" branch (of course after you settle your conflict if any)

*NOTE
If you are in "development" and do (assuming your remote "development" branch name is "development" as well):

```
git pull (or git pull --rebase) origin development
```

It will merge into your "development" branch (of course after you settle your conflict if any)

Which is of course something you don't want

---

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention about merging.

To merge your local branches:

I am going to assume you want to merge your "newBranch" branch to "development" branch once you pull from master. The steps are below:

1. Be on "development" branch

   git checkout development
2. Merge "newBranch" branch to "development" branch

   git merge newBranch

Once you are done, you would want to delete your "newBranch" branch before pushing to server repo.

To delete local "newBranch" branch:

```
git branch -d newBranch
```

To delete server "newBranch" branch:

```
git push origin --delete newBranch
```

Check that you have done everything right (if is right, newBranch should not show up):

```
git branch -a
```